# Clearing Object Duplicates In a vector produces infinite loop

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector called:

```
vector<MiniPair> miniPairVector;
```

MiniPair object has 2 property inside,1 is an integer `docNumber` other is a string `word`

I am trying to clear duplicates in this vector which means that if docNumber and word exist in another object inside vector remove the duplicates

This is what i have tried but it is producing an infinite loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < miniPairVector.size(); i++) {

    for (int k = i + 1; k < miniPairVector.size(); k++) {

        if (miniPairVector[i].getDocNumber() == miniPairVector[k].getDocNumber() && miniPairVector[i].getWord() == miniPairVector[k].getWord()) {
            cout << "i am erasing" << endl;
            miniPairVector.erase(miniPairVector.begin() + k);

        }

    }

}
```

this is the minipair class:

```
#pragma once
// classes example
#ifndef MINIPAIR_H
#define MINIPAIR_H
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MiniPair {
    friend bool operator<(MiniPair const &a, MiniPair const &b) {

        return a.docNumber < b.docNumber || a.docNumber == b.docNumber && a.word < b.word;
    }
    friend bool operator==(MiniPair const &a, MiniPair const &b) {

        return a.docNumber == b.docNumber && a.word == b.word;
    }
private:
    string word;
    int docNumber;

public:
    MiniPair();
    MiniPair(string word, int docNumber);
    string getWord();
    int getDocNumber();

};
#endif
```

Comment: Use std::unique. Your implémentation is not safe. Implement correctly operator < for MiniPair...

Comment: This is a fairly inefficient way of going about this.

Comment: So if `miniPairVector` contained `n` elements, your code will have O(n^2) complexity.  Imagine if `n` is 1000.

Comment: thats true thats why it is failing.i never used  unique by the way

Comment: @lastpeony4 -- Does the order matter?  If not, then you can just simply `std::sort` the vector, and use algorithm functions such as `std::unique / vector.erase` to remove the duplicates.

Comment: no order does not matter.if its that short can you write an answer

Answer (score 3):

My presumption is that you are doing this for a class.

First, while this may not be relevant for the problem you're solving write now because of class imposed constraints, this is a poor way of implementing this. When implemented correctly the number of comparisons will be something like `miniPairVector.size() * miniPairVector.size()`. That's a lot of comparisons, and way more than you actually need.

If I were trying to do this in a non-toy (or non-assignment) program, I would use the `<algorithm>` section of the standard library. I would use `::std::sort` and then `::std::unique`.

Here's how I would do it using those two:

```
#include <algorithm>

void remove_dupes(::std::vector<MiniPair> &minipair_vec)
{
    ::std::sort(minipair_vec.begin(), minipair_vec.end(),
                [](MiniPair const &a, MiniPair const &b) -> bool {
                    return (a.getDocNumber() < b.getDocNumber())
                           || ((a.getDocNumber() == b.getDocNumber())
                               && (a.getWord() < b.getWord())));
               }); // End lambda and sort.
     auto newend = ::std::unique(minipair_vec.begin(), minipair_vec.end(),
                                [](MiniPair const &a, MiniPair const &b) -> bool {
                                   return a.getDocNumber() == b.getDocNumber()
                                          && a.getWord() == b.getWord();
                                }); // End lambda and unique.
     minipair_vec.resize(newend - minipair_vec.begin());
}
```

I have tested it, so it should work just fine.

The general lesson is that if you find yourself looping, go through this set of questions:

- Am I indexing into a linear data structure? If so, why am I using indexes instead of iterators?
- Is there an algorithm that already does what I need, or can a couple of algorithms be easily composed to do what I need?

The code I presented should run in a time that's proportional to `minipair_vec.size() * ::std::log2(minipair_vec.size())`. The code you wrote would run in a time proportional to `minipair_vec.size() * minipair_vec.size()` (once you got it to work), which is a lot longer for a large list.

Comment: The `sort` lambda could just be `return std::tie(a.getDocNumber(), a.getWord()) < std::tie(b.getDocNumber(), b.getWord());`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - It could be. I didn't think of that, and I'm a little reluctant to add it. Given the nature of the question I would like things to be as clear as possible, and I feel that adds requiring to know about `::std::tie`.

Answer (score 2):

A C++98 solution:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct MiniPair {
    int docNumber;
    std::string word;
    friend bool operator<(MiniPair const &a, MiniPair const &b) {
        return a.docNumber < b.docNumber || a.docNumber == b.docNumber && a.word < b.word;
    }
    friend bool operator==(MiniPair const &a, MiniPair const &b) {
        return a.docNumber == b.docNumber && a.word == b.word;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<MiniPair> miniPairVector;
    // fill miniPairVector with data
    std::sort(miniPairVector.begin(), miniPairVector.end());
    miniPairVector.erase(std::unique(miniPairVector.begin(), miniPairVector.end()), miniPairVector.end());
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you can declare a friend inline like that? Your solution is a lot cleaner than mine is. The biggest disadvantage is that it basically defines a global ordering for `MiniPair` which may or may not be appropriate.

Comment: i tried this it is not working non of the dublicates are deleted vector size is same

Comment: True @Omnifarious, but you can always override the ordering when needed with a functor. And, yes, inline friends make it work very well with many compilers even in the template case.

Comment: hi i edited question added MiniPair class can you check

Comment: @lastpeony4 That dependes on the data. As the code is written it assumes that the pair together are the key. *But* if only, e.g. `docNumber` is the key, then change the `operator<`' and `operator==` functions to reflect that.

Comment: no if both are equal i mean docnumber and the word i need to delete actually yours look correct

Comment: @lastpeony4, the solution seems to work. I checked with `int main() {
    std::vector<MiniPair> miniPairVector{{"first", 1},{"second", 2},{"third", 3}, {"second", 2},};
    std::cout << miniPairVector.size() << '\n';
    // fill miniPairVector with data
    std::sort(miniPairVector.begin(), miniPairVector.end());
    miniPairVector.erase(std::unique(miniPairVector.begin(), miniPairVector.end()), miniPairVector.end());
    std::cout << miniPairVector.size() << '\n';
}
`